# Unity resize layout

Tags: unity-game-engine, resize, timeline, unity-timeline

My unity timeline looks like this after clicking on somthing wrong i dont remember
any solutions please ?[My Unity Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIwr8.png)

Comment: Please, read "how to ask a question" document on stack overflow before asking one

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that on the "3 dots" on the right you have evryinthing with a tick and press the buttons on the left until you find your previous layout that you preferred.

Comment: Please i cant find the buttons on the left i pressed the 3 dots and a list show with "Lock" " Maximize" "Close tab" "Add tab".

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your mouse cursor on the vertical scroll of the timeline.
   Drag the handle of the scroll to the bottom
2. Move your mouse cursor on the bottom line of the Animation Track panel.
3. After the cursor is changed to the vertical arrow, then drag it to the top

[Take a look at this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUoG6.png)

If it doesn't work, let me know